# Android drawable stops being reachable

Tags: android, eclipse, android-drawable

The is a weird one:

Ref

```
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mypic);
```

At first everything was running fine, except the image (which I draw) was missing some shade. So I edit my image away from eclipse and then replace the old `mypic.png` with the new one. But eclipse refused to see the new image, as if it had already cached the old one and was using that. So I change from `mypic.png` to `mypic1.png`, then the line of code kept returning image as `null`. So I gave up and changed the image name back to `mypic.png` (I figure I'd let it use the cached one), but eclipse kept on returning `image = null`.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleaned the project? Sometimes you need that to trigger AAPT to recompile resources.

Answer (score 0):

after modifying png images do F5 on res folder so that eclipse see the the new image

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me is this: instead of doing a hot replace and then F5, I removed the images manually first. Only then, I add the new edited version of the images. For some reason eclipse saw the image then. I am still baffled at the problem and doubt it is reproducible. I am including this here in case someone else somehow gets the same problem. F5 didn't work; cleaning didn't work; restarting eclipse and the emulator didn't work. It's all magic to me.